# How to recreate Oracle db from .ora and .dbf?

Tags: oracle, recovery, datafile

I have a number of files left from a previous Oracle db and I would like to create a new one from the files.

The files include:

- `init_locdb.ora`
- 16 `.dbf` files
- `spfilelocdb.ora`
- log files
- `.ctl`

Could you tell me is it possible to recreate a new Oracle database from the files so it is identical (almost identical) to the previous one?

Answer (score -1):

The various data files that comprise the physical storage of the Oracle database instance can vary depending on the operating system, endian format, and pretty sure some of the files may have a hostname hiding in them somewhere.  And if those files were obtained from a database instance that was running, there is no way those files could be used to recreate a usable database instance, even on the exact same server as the files came on.

The `*.ctl` files are updated every 3 seconds or so with timestamps and pointers (oversimplifying but fairly accurate), so sorry, no way.

Comment: that is not true. A database consists of exactly the files the op tells us. The hostname isn't hidden in the files. Usually you will be able to start he database again.